# How do we determine the proportions of hydrogen to helium (to other elements) that make up the Sun given the absorption spectra?

Tags: spectroscopy, light

I am reading about the composition of the Sun and how it is made up of mostly hydrogen (~90%) and helium (>10%) and other elements with much smaller quantities. The explains that different elements give different absoprtion spectra (different lines) yet I do not understand how the proportions were calculated. Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: Lines differ not only in terms of position, but also their *intensities*.

Comment: Also I think that such an analysis should assume many things as well as modelling the star. I think the only access is to what directly radiates, photosphere and the exterior

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would be better on Astronomy.SE

Comment: Spectral lines and how they work is clearly a part of chemistry even when applied to the sun. After all one of the elements–helium–was first discovered in the spectral lines of the sun.

Comment: I agree is chemistry but as I said before there is no way to know the composition of  *the sun* in a straightforward way. It would be like to look at an almost opaque  bottle to decide its content. Still more direct evidence can be attained for the photosphere, chromosphere and corona.

Comment: @Mithoron the question is on spectroscopic methods...just because it is not your preferred area of study does not mean it is off-topic. I could have just asked how can the proportions of an element be identified through line spectroscopy giving the Sun as an example..